# Objective-C questions

Tags: objective-c

I`m newbie in objective-c and I have some questions:

1. What is an IMP?
2. What is msgSend function?

Answer (score 3):

The IMP is an IMplementation Pointer, which is basically the hook that determines what gets run upon receipt of a message (like foo length). You don't usually need them unless you're getting down and dirty; it's usually easier to deal with selectors.

> 6.1 What is an IMP ?
>
> ```
>    It's the C type of a method implementation pointer, a function
> ```
>
> pointer
>          to the function that implements an Objective-C method. It is defined
>          to return id and takes two hidden arguments, self and _cmd :
>
> ```
>    typedef id (*IMP)(id self,SEL _cmd,...);
>
> 6.2 How do I get an IMP given a SEL ?
>
>    This can be done by sending a methodFor: message :
>
> IMP myImp = [myObject methodFor:mySel];
>
> 6.3 How do I send a message given an IMP ?
>
>    By dereferencing the function pointer. The following are all
>    equivalent :
>
> [myObject myMessage];
>
>    or
>
> IMP myImp = [myObject methodFor:@selector(myMessage)];
> myImp(myObject,@selector(myMessage));
>
>    or
>
> [myObject perform:@selector(myMessage)];
> ```

From section 6.1 of the [Objective C FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/computer-lang/Objective-C/faq/).

As for the msgSend, that's the way you invoke a remote message on another object; objc_msgSend(foo,@selector(bar)) is roughly the same as [foo bar]. But these are all low-level implementation details; you rarely (if ever) need to use the expanded calls for Objective C code, since you can do @selector to get hold of a method and performSelector: to invoke it on any object.